# hpasmcli documentation or manual

Tags: hp-proliant

I use the HP health suite for a Proliant server and i get following output:

```
# hpasmcli -s "show fans;"

Fan  Location        Present Speed  of max  Redundant  Partner  Hot-pluggable
---  --------        ------- -----  ------  ---------  -------  -------------
#1   PROCESSOR_ZONE  Yes     NORMAL  5%      Yes        2        Yes
#2   PROCESSOR_ZONE  Yes     NORMAL  5%      Yes        1        Yes
#3   PROCESSOR_ZONE  Yes     NORMAL  5%      Yes        1        Yes
#4   PROCESSOR_ZONE  Yes     NORMAL  5%      Yes        1        Yes
#5   I/O_ZONE        Yes     NORMAL  10%     Yes        1        Yes
#6   I/O_ZONE        Yes     NORMAL  10%     Yes        1        Yes
```

Fine. But what is the meaning of Speed=NORMAL of max=10% Partner=2 ?

Where can i find further information about this command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run "man hpasmcli" for descriptions of the command. You can also use "hplog -f" for quick fan status. I usually run this in conjunction with "hplog -t" to obtain the temperature readings as well.

To answer your question about the output, the speed indicates that the variable speed fans are running at a normal rate (in terms of RPM). The % of max field shows the percentage of the maximum fan rotation speed that the fan is presently running at.

The partner field displays information about the redundant fan pairings. Some Proliant systems (DL740 G1, for instance) pair the redundant fans such that they are the failover for one another. Your output indicates that Fan #1 is the failover fan for fans 2-6 and that a failure of fan #1 will also require fan #2 to compensate. Losing fans #1 and #2 will result in a system thermal failure.

This is the output of a Proliant DL740. There are only two fans, so they complement each other.

```
Fan  Location        Present Speed  of max  Redundant  Partner  Hot-pluggable
---  --------        ------- -----  ------  ---------  -------  -------------
#1   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL N/A     Yes        2        Yes           
#2   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL N/A     Yes        1        Yes
```

This is the output of a DL380 G6. The fans are arranged in a single row and have no redundant pairs or partners.

```
Fan  Location        Present Speed  of max  Redundant  Partner  Hot-pluggable
---  --------        ------- -----  ------  ---------  -------  -------------
#1   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL  13%     Yes        0        Yes           
#2   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL  13%     Yes        0        Yes           
#3   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL  29%     Yes        0        Yes           
#4   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL  29%     Yes        0        Yes           
#5   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL  29%     Yes        0        Yes           
#6   SYSTEM          Yes     NORMAL  29%     Yes        0        Yes
```

Further reading at HP's Linux Support page: https://web.archive.org/web/20041118032510/http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/documentation.html

And the Managing ProLiant servers guide (PDF):
https://web.archive.org/web/20110305073836/http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00223285/c00223285.pdf